# sis671 video driver

Tags: drivers, xorg, video, sis-graphics

I am in a desperate situation. I have a laptop with SIS 771/671 graphics. I migrated to Ubuntu from Arch Linux recently. When I started using Arch Linux, I had trouble getting my video card to work, but I solved it by installing xf86-video-sis671 package. Unfortunately, the source code was located on Gitorious, and gitorious doesn't exist anymore and the only driver that worked for me is gone too. I deleted it when I installed Ubuntu and I must use the vesa driver instead. Is there anybody who has the same card and the driver? I am sure that the driver must be somewhere, I hope that somebody can send it to me. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is still looking for it, I found a fork that works as well. https://github.com/gununu/xf86-video-sis-stable

Comment: I tried a similar one before and it did not work.

Comment: Will you please add output of `lspci -nn | grep VGA` to your question. I will try it too. But I need to make sure you have the same adapter.

Comment: the output looks like this: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS] 771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter [1039:6351] (rev 10)
note that I needed to add "ShadowFB" "true" to the device section in the config

Answer (score 0):

There is the driver. For instance in [my github](https://github.com/hanipouspilot/xf86-video-sismedia-0.9.1).

But it will work only on Ubuntu 12.04 with Xorg version 1.11.

The last Xorg version supported is 1.12.

You will need to install the original 12.04, or install 12.04.5 and downgrade the Xorg.

Comment: are you sure that this is the same driver? I don't think so, because the driver I was using was working with the latest Xorg, that is 1.17. anyway, thank you. btw the driver was a fork of xf86-video-sisimedia and it was called xf86-video-sis671

Comment: So that is that fork. I have a laptop with this adapter. It does not matter how it is called.

Comment: But you will need some packages to be installed to get this package built. I can give you a guide, if you need.

Comment: thanks, but I need it to work with the latest Xorg, not just 1.12. I am going to install openSUSE as well, and use that driver too. opensuse doesn't have releases with 5 years support.

Comment: That will not give you normal resolution. I tried a lot and many people did too. It is not feasible.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I found a fork of that driver and it works well. it compiles with Xorg 1.17 and the resolution is normal: https://github.com/gununu/xf86-video-sis-stable

Answer (score 0):

this solved me:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

uncomment the line

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

to p.ex.

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
```

save and

```
sudo update-grub
```

On next boot you'll have the desired screen resolution.